# Error unkown filetype although it is declared in a header file and included

Tags: c, gcc, include, makefile

i have an error that I do not understand. I can get rid of the error if I just put the include in the mail.c file and not in the mail.h file. My code looks like this:

The mail.h file:

```
#ifndef MAIL_H
#define MAIL_H
//Normal needed headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//Custom headers
#include "pop3.h"
#include "pasw.h"
#include "rese.h"


#define NAME_SIZE 100 //Defines the length of e.g. the user name
#define PASSW_SIZE 100 //Defines the length of the password
#define ADD_SPACE 10 //Defines some additional space for arrays

#define HELPTEXT "help.txt" //Defines the name of the help.txt file

enum bool {true, false};
typedef enum bool bool;

#endif
```

The pop3.h file:

```
#ifndef POP3
#define POP3

// Open SSl headers
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

//Needed for the password input to not show the password
#include <termios.h>

//Normal needed headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//Custom headers
#include "mail.h"
#include "pasw.h"
#include "rese.h"

void pop3(unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *);
int GetUserPassw(unsigned char *, unsigned char *);
int login(BIO *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, bool, bool);
int GetUsername(unsigned char *;);
int GetInput(unsigned char*, int);
int GetNumberOfMessages(BIO *);
void RetrieveEmail(BIO *);

#endif
```

In mail. c I have included mail.h and in pop3.c I have included pop3.h. The error I get is:

```
gcc -lcrypto -lssl -c mail.c 
In file included from mail.h:10:0,
             from mail.c:11:
pop3.h:24:69: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
 int login(BIO *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, bool, bool);
                                                                 ^
pop3.h:24:75: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
 int login(BIO *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, bool, bool);
                                                                       ^
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'mail.o' failed
 make: *** [mail.o] Error 1
```

And my Makefile looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-lcrypto -lssl -o
OFLAGS=-lcrypto -lssl -c
RM=rm -i

all: mail

mail:   mail.o pop3.o pasw.o rese.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) mail mail.o pop3.o pasw.o rese.o

mail.o: mail.c
    $(CC) $(OFLAGS) mail.c 

pop3.o: pop3.c
    $(CC) $(OFLAGS) pop3.c

pasw.o: pasw.c
    $(CC) $(OFLAGS) pasw.c

rese.o: rese.c
    $(CC) $(OFLAGS) rese.c

clean:
    rm *.o mail
```

Before I have changed the file structure a bit it has worked. But I can get rid of this problem by puting the include "commands" out of mail.h and into mail.c.

I am looking forward to hear from you.

King regards,
Greenality

Comment: Don't try to define you own `bool` type, include `<stdbool.h>` instead.

Comment: There is no "filetype" here.

Comment: BTW `CFLAGS` <-> `OFLAGS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pop3.h` you use the type `bool` in the function declaration of

```
int login(BIO *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, bool, bool);
```

But when `pop3.h` is included into `mail.h`, `bool` is not defined at that point yet where `pop3.h` is included.

As you also include `mail.h` into `pop3.h`, you have a cyclic dependency between the header files, so you'd have to create its own file for the type `bool` and `#include` it into the `pop3.h` header. An alternative is to clean up your header dependencies properly as `pop3.h` has only a dependency on `#include <openssl/bio.h>` and the `bool` type.

Also instead of creating your own boolean type, use the `bool` from `stdbool.h` which is also properly convertible unlike yours and uses a real boolean type if the compiler provides it.

So your `pop3.h` would end up as

```
#ifndef POP3
#define POP3

#include <stdbool.h>
// Open SSl headers
#include <openssl/bio.h>


void pop3(unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *);
int GetUserPassw(unsigned char *, unsigned char *);
int login(BIO *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned char *, bool, bool);
int GetUsername(unsigned char *;);
int GetInput(unsigned char*, int);
int GetNumberOfMessages(BIO *);
void RetrieveEmail(BIO *);

#endif
```

while the missing header files required for the implementation will be directly included into the `pop3.c` file:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "mail.h"
#include "pasw.h"
#include "rese.h"
```

I can't help you with `mail.h` as it's missing its interface. Everything that you have in your `mail.h` should actually be in `mail.c` as it's about implementation details.
Only what you want to provide to users of your `mail.c` implementation should be part of the interface in `mail.h`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all read my comment. Second of all, you define the type `bool` *after* you include the headers that depend on the type.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling mail.c, the file first includes the content of mail.h, which in turn includes the content of pop.h, which attempts to include mail.h but ends up getting nothing from the file due to `MAIL_H` being already defined.

Since pop.h was included *before* `enum bool` was defined in mail.h, the content of pop.h has no knowledge of what `bool` is. Therefore the compiler error. Simply define `enum bool` before including pop.h in mail.h should solve the problem.